# Getting a substring in Ruby by x number of chars

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to produce some Ruby code that will take a string and return a new one, with a number x number of characters removed from its end - these can be actual letters, numbers, spaces etc.

Ex: given the following string

`a_string = "a1wer4zx"`

I need a simple way to get the same string, minus - say - the 3 last characters. In the case above, that would be "a1wer". The way I'm doing it right now seems very convoluted:

```
an_array = a_string.split(//,(a_string.length-2))
an_array.pop
new_string = an_array.join
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is convoluted, and, it's good that you had that feeling. Ruby in whole is an elegant language so when it feels like you're having to jump through hoops to do something, it's a warning you are probably going about it the wrong way. Of course there are going to be times that the solution is inelegant, because that's the nature of programming. Still, good Ruby really is zen-like, so go with the flow. :-)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

How about this?

```
s[0, s.length - 3]
```

Or this

```
s[0..-4]
```

**edit**

```
s = "abcdefghi"
puts s[0, s.length - 3]  # => abcdef
puts s[0..-4]            # => abcdef
```

Comment: Could someone explain what does s[0..-4] do?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it would certainly look like it wraps around the string. So doing `s[0..-1]` would return absdefgh. Usually `..` is used to represent a range

Answer (score 16):

Use something like this:

```
s = "abcdef"
new_s = s[0..-2] # new_s = "abcde"
```

See the `slice` method here: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html

Answer (score 8):

Another option could be to use the `slice` method

```
a_string = "a1wer4zx"
a_string.slice(0..5) 
=> "a1wer4"
```

Documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-slice

Answer (score 3):

if you need it in rails you can use [first](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/String.html#method-i-first) ([source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9e67954dcfdc92f1087a03c0b1c61251d993e270/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/access.rb#L75))

```
s = '1234567890'
x = 4
s.first(s.length - x) # => "123456"
```

there is also [last](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/String.html#method-i-last) ([source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9e67954dcfdc92f1087a03c0b1c61251d993e270/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/access.rb#L95))

```
s.last(2) # => "90"
```

alternatively check [from/to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/String.html#method-i-from)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is getting the list of [`chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-chars) of the string, [`take`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take)ing x chars and [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-join)ing back to a string:

```
[13] pry(main)> 'abcdef'.chars.take(2).join
=> "ab"
[14] pry(main)> 'abcdef'.chars.take(20).join
=> "abcdef"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know a lot of people already said this, but I think the best option is this:

```
'abcdefg'[0..-4] # should return 'abcd'
```

Something important to realize is that the returned string is inclusive on both endpoints. A lot of string parsing methods (e.g., the java and javascript substring method) are inclusive on the first endpoint and exclusive on the last, but this is NOT the case with the above way.

```
'abcdefghijklm'[1..5] # returns 'bcdef'


// substring method in java or javascript returns 'bcde'

'abcdefghijklm'.substring(1, 5);
```